# Recover bootable Win 7 recovery drive from an image

Tags: windows-7, boot, disk-image

I have [a laptop](https://support.hp.com/us-en/product/hp-elitebook-folio-9470m-ultrabook/5271146/model/5271149?sku=C7Q21AW) that came with a Windows 7/OEM license, for which I still have the product key. I have replaced this OS with another (Linux), and I'm trying to re-install the former. Here's the problem statement: I used to have a working USB recovery drive, but no longer have it. But in the interim, I made an image of it, on an external HDD, using [gnome-disk-utility](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Disks). It is named 'win-live.img'. That is all I have to restore Windows on my laptop. I tried recovering the recovery drive using the same utility, but it is not mountable, and it's not usable for booting. IS there any way I can recover win-live.img?

[image: disk utility view of the source file]
[image: File manager view of the source file]
[image: Recovery process]
[image: Target drive]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you wrote the image to `/dev/sdc1` instead of `/dev/sdc`. I don't know if gnome-disk-utility has a menu/button somewhere else for you to write an image to a drive instead of one of its partition. If you couldn't find such menu/button, you can do the right thing with `cp`:

```
# cp /path/to/win-live.img /dev/sdc
```

In my experience this is not necessary but as a reassurance, you can run:

```
# sync /dev/sdc
```

after the `cp` command returned, to flush the cached data (dirty pages) to the drive.

Make sure `/dev/sdc` still refers to the desired target drive before running the command though.